# Qsort array | warning: initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, qsort

I am compiling this program in GCC, using Wall command and it appears all clear. But my college online platform is giving a compile time error

9.c: In function 'compare_int':
9.c:8: warning: initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type
9.c:9: warning: initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Here's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 1000

int c=0;

int compare_int(const void *pa, const void *pb) {
  const int ((*a)[1]) = pa;
  const int ((*b)[1]) = pb;
  if ( (*a)[0] < (*b)[0] ) return -1;
  if ( (*a)[0] > (*b)[0] ) return +1;
  return 0;
}

void check(int m, int lastNum, int startIndex, int v[][2], int n){
  if (lastNum >= m) printf("%d\n", c);
  else{
    int i,max=0;
    for (i=startIndex;v[i][0]<=lastNum;i++){
      if (v[i][0] <= lastNum)
    if (v[i][1] > max) max = v[i][1];
    }
    c++;
    check(m, max, i,v, n);
  }
}

int main(){
  int m,n,i;
  int line[MAX][2];
  scanf("%d", &m);
  scanf("%d", &n);
  for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    scanf("%d %d", &line[i][0], &line [i][1]);
  }
  qsort(line, n, sizeof line[0], compare_int);
  check(m, 0, 0, line, n); 
  return 0;
}
```

The program is supposed to read 2 numbers. First one is the length of a path starting in 0, and the second one is the number of pairs(not ordered) that can fill it. Then using greedy algorithm it has to find how many segments it needs to fullfill it. The problem here is on quick sorting the matrix with pairs, apparently it has some pointer error but I can't find what's wrong here... I guess it's somewhat basic but I can't understand it at all.

Help please!

Comment: 6
5
0 2
3 5
4 6
3 8
2 4
3
[Inferior 1 (process 12909) exited normally]

Comment: Yes, I used gdb and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is complaining about the initializations of local variables `a` and `b` in this fragment:

> ```
> int compare_int(const void *pa, const void *pb) {
>   const int ((*a)[1]) = pa;
>   const int ((*b)[1]) = pb;
> ```

The compiler is right.  Mostly.

Consider variable `a`.  [Cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) interprets its declaration like so:

> declare a as pointer to array 1 of const int

Note in particular that it is not `a` itself that is `const` (there is no way to declare an array `const`); rather, it is the *elements* of `a` that are `const`.  This is a distinction without much difference, except to a picky compiler that observes that function parameter `pa` is declared as a pointer to a `const` object, and `a` is declared as a pointer to a non-`const` object, so that assigning the former to the latter loses (technically) the `const`-ness.

The best solution is probably to stop trying to be so clever.  Why declare `a` and `b` as pointers to one-element arrays, when the whole point is to compare the objects they point to (as `int`s)?  You have to roll out tricky syntax in the local variable declarations and also everywhere you use the values.  I'd just do this:

```
int compare_int(const void *pa, const void *pb) {
   int a = *(const int *)pa;
   int b = *(const int *)pb;

   if ( a < b ) return -1;
   // ...
```

Comment: It worked, thanks!

I am not so sure about the compare_int function. I tried so much to 'sort by column' the 2d array, and it wasn't working. That piece of code was found online but yours is much simpler and easier to read.

Comment: Your solution causes undefined behavior due to strict aliasing. Types int* and int(*)[2] are not compatible.

Comment: @2501, you are right that `int *` and `int(*)[2]` are not compatible types.  I didn't look carefully at the `qsort()` call, focusing instead on the comparison function.  Nevertheless, that's not enough to produce a strict-aliasing violation.  If `pa` (for example) points to an `int[2]`, then it necessarily *also* points to that array's first element.  Converting `pa` to a `const int *` and dereferencing it accesses that `int` via an lvalue of compatible type.

Comment: Yes I agree, 6.5.7 mentions aggregate types.

Comment: Hi, I'm revisiting this post. The aliasing rule for aggregate types doesn't apply here, since in this case int  is used as an lvalue, not the array (aggregate). Luckily no strict aliasing occurs since the casted (converted) pointer does point to an int.